# How LoadString() works in VC++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am working on an MFC application where when I write Something like this:`CString sName; sName.LoadString(IDS_NAME_STRING)` it works fine but when I try to write while initializing in one line like `CString sName = sName.LoadString(IDS_NAME_STRING)`, I am getting error

> Error  C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'BOOL' to 'ATL::CStringT<char,StrTraitMFC_DLL<char,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<_CharType>>>'

I am not getting what's wrong with the latter statement. Can anyone help me to understand this error?

Comment: The `LoadString` member function return a `BOOL` (integer) result, indicating whether or not the call succeeded. Why do you think you should be assigned that value to the string itself?

Comment: Check the documentation of `CString` please. `CSting::LoadSrtring()` specifically...

Comment: [LoadString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class?view=msvc-170#loadstring) amazingly doesn't return the loaded string, but a BOOL (`bool`) telling us if it found the string.

Comment: Trying too often to do things "all in one go" is not the best way to approach writing good C++ code. Stick with the original - that works!

Comment: well, that seems the correct explanation, is there any way we can combine these into 1 line? like declaration and initialization in the same line?

Comment: @AdrianMole agree, but I got a comment from by team lead, can we combine these in one line? really don't know how it helps but wanted to have some solid explanation if choose not to go with one line statement.

Comment: Well, there's nothing stopping you from putting the two *statements* on one line, but you can't declare a `CString` *and* load it in one statement.

Comment: In general, you can write your own class and add separate constructor for `int`. Then you can write `CMyClass sname(IDS_NAME_STRING)` in one line. I am not saying you should do that though, because it makes the code more complicated (I would also avoid deriving from `CString`, or at least use private inheritance if deriving from `CString`). It's better to just write two lines of code. The compiled executable will be the same size or smaller.

Comment: *"is there any way we can combine these into 1 line?"* - Yes, of course: `CString sName; sName.LoadString(IDS_NAME_STRING);`. There, one line. If the question was rather whether you can combine those into a single statement, then sure, that's also possible, by use of the most basic means of abstraction we have: Write a function `CString load_string(int id);`.

Comment: Or use this: `CString sName(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDS_NAME_STRING));`

Answer (score 2):

[`CString::LoadString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class#loadstring) returns a value of type `BOOL`. That's what the error message is telling you. It turned out to be a bit longer as it includes the full template instantiations. It's ultimately saying

> cannot convert from 'BOOL' to 'CString'

The solution is what you already have:

```cpp
CString sName;
sName.LoadString(IDS_NAME_STRING);
```

If you'd rather have that as a single statement, you'll have to implement a function for it, e.g.

```cpp
CString load_string(uint32_t id) {
    CString s;
    s.LoadString(id);
    return s;
}
```

With that you can write

```cpp
auto s = load_string(IDS_NAME_STRING);
```

Note that the function `load_string` mirrors the behavior of the initial code: If a string resource with any given ID cannot be found, it returns an empty string. If you'd rather have failure communicated to clients you could throw an exception.

Comment: I got an understanding of the issue. I think first declaring and then initializing is a simple approach. Now , I can answer why we can not declare in the same line.